# undefined reference to boost::filesystem::detail::copy_file

Tags: c++, boost

Using boost_1_53_0 I am getting the above mentioned error. But interestingly I am also using boost::filesystem::create_directory and boost::tokenizer<>::iterator and some other boost functions which works very well. Am i missing something to include something in library path ? or it could be some other reason ?

Your suggestions/comments ... please ?

Comment: A lot of boosts functionality is provided in headers, so the library does not need to be linked.

Answer (score 1):

As explained on Boost intro pages (http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_56_0/more/getting_started/windows.html#header-only-libraries)

> most Boost libraries are header-only: they consist entirely of header files containing templates and inline functions, and require no separately-compiled library binaries or special treatment when linking.

But Boost.Filesystem is one of the Boost libraries that must be built separately.